# <form:select> items from list with default prompt

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

The following code works correctly in my jsp:

```
<form:select path="propertyPath" >  
    <form:options items="${modelObject}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```

However, I want to have a default nulled value with the label "Select" as a prompt to the user.  I've tried the following:

```
<form:select path="propertyPath" >
    <form:option label="Select" value=""/>
    <form:options items="${modelObject}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```

This populates the drop down labels correctly, however on submitting I find that the itemValues have all been set to empty.  Does anyone know why these values are being removed when I add the additional  field?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @user2774284 can you try something like this it's another option:

```
<form:select path="" cssClass="" id="yourId" value="${modelObject}">
    <option value="" label="Select" ></option>
    <option value="yourValue" <c:if test="${modelObject == yourValue}"> selected </c:if>>yourValue</option>
    <option value="yourValue" <c:if test="${modelObject == yourValue}"> selected </c:if>>yourValue</option>
    <option value="yourValue" <c:if test="${modelObject == yourValue}"> selected </c:if>>yourValue</option>
</form:select>
```

The code above work if you knows value (`yourValue`) from modelObject. Finally the JSP convert JSTL to DOM HTML conventional.

**I hope help you :)**